# ggplot2 two level bar charts (aim with same size of bar)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot two-level bar charts with following code,

with dataset

```
Date <- as.yearmon(rep(as.yearmon(c("Jun 2013", "Jun 2014"), format="%b %Y"), 4))[1:7]
Mktg.Al <- c("CX", "CX", "GA", "GA", "HX", "HX", "KA")
Seats <- sample(300:1000,7)
data <- data.frame(Date, Mktg.Al, Seats)
```

code for plotting

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(Date), y=Seats, fill=Mktg.Al)) +   
geom_bar(position = "Dodge", stat="identity", size=10) +
geom_text(aes(label=Seats), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)
```

[image]

I would like to have same size of each bars

Many thanks

Comment: Especially with plotting question, it's important to include sample data to make your problem [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) if you want specific solutions.=. We have no idea what data you are feeding to your plot nor can we test possible answers before posting.

Comment: @MrFlick, Please see amendment.

Answer (score 1):

Try mentioning all aesthetics at one place. this might work. i am not sure because you havent provided any sample data to check. use `position="dodge"` in geom text as well

```
ggplot(DATA.Yty.agg, aes(x = as.factor(Date),y = Seats,label=Seats,fill = Mktg.Al)) +   
geom_bar(position = "Dodge", stat="identity") +
geom_text(vjust=-0.2,position="dodge")
```

Comment: many thanks. as there are different number of bars for 2013 and 2014. while i would like to have same size for each bars. Do you know how i can make that? Thanks again

Comment: I am not sure but try `size` in `geom_bar` it might help

Comment: i mean my belows answer XD

Answer (score 1):

I solved the question by adding following graph after create the `data.frame` `data`

```
colnames <- colnames(data)
data <- as.data.frame(xtabs(formula = Seats ~ Date + Mktg.Al, data=data))
colnames(data) <- colnames
```

In total,

```
Date <- as.yearmon(rep(as.yearmon(c("Jun 2013", "Jun 2014"), format="%b %Y"), 4))[1:7]
Mktg.Al <- c("CX", "CX", "GA", "GA", "HX", "HX", "KA")
Seats <- sample(300:1000,7)
data <- data.frame(Date, Mktg.Al, Seats)
colnames <- colnames(data)
data <- as.data.frame(xtabs(formula = Seats ~ Date + Mktg.Al, data=data))
colnames(data) <- colnames

ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(Date), y=Seats, fill=Mktg.Al)) +   
geom_bar(position = "Dodge", stat="identity", size=10) +
geom_text(aes(label=Seats), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)
```

Output graph would be
[image]